# How do I create a "Spend and Save" style promotion? 10% off $99, 15% off $149, 20% off $199 with no coupon

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions

I'd like to create a promotion where the customer saves 10% if they spend $99, 15% if they spend $149, and 20% if they spend $199.  It works with just having one of these rules but I'd like to apply all 3 three rules so the customer can save more when they spend more. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

You need to structure three separate rules as such:

- A 10% off rule >= 99 < 149
- A 15% off rule >=149 < 199
- a 20% off rule >=199

In Magento's shopping cart promotions the rules would look like this:

[image]

[image]

<strike>**MAKE SURE** you tell it to stop further rules from processing and sort these rules so that they do not apply on top of each other. It's better to make the bigger discount **the lower priority** so it gets processed first (stopping the other rules from applying).</strike>

The rules are exclusive of each other as I designed them, no need to worry about priority!